# Explanation of p-value in ols_step_forward_p function of olsrr package

Tags: r

Consider the following example:-(taken from the e.g. of R documentation)

```
model <- lm(y ~ ., data = surgical)
ols_step_forward_p(model)
```

The documentation says that it will be employing the Forward Stepwise method to select the final model. If I am not wrong, doesn't this forward selection is based on observing the p values of the following test statistic:-

[image]

where we are considering a model with K predictors all total. RSS denotes the residual sum of squares and the subscript p and K denote the RSS of a model with p and K predictors respectively.

If I do not give the command `penter` in `ols_step_forward_p` function what default p-value is chosen?

Comment: what package is `ols_step_forward_p` from? It's not part of base R. ...

Comment: It is from ```olsrr``` package

Answer (score 1):

`ols_step_forward_p` has documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/olsrr/versions/0.5.3/topics/ols_step_forward_p) (also via `?olsrr::ols_step_forward_p` if you have the package installed)

The second entry ("S3 method for default") says

> ols_step_forward_p(model, **penter = 0.3**,
>     progress = FALSE, details = FALSE, ...)

(emphasis added).

This means that the default value of `penter` is 0.3.

To see in more detail what's going on, you can look at the code for `olsrr::ols_step_forward_p.default`. Here's the relevant code export::

```
for (i in seq_len(len_p)) {
            predictors <- c(preds, all_pred[i])
            m <- lm(paste(response, "~", paste(predictors, collapse = " + ")), 
                l)
            m_sum <- Anova(m)
            pvals[i] <- m_sum$`Pr(>F)`[ppos]
        }
```

So you can see that the p-value is based on the F-test from `car::Anova`. See `?car::Anova.lm` for more details ...

Comment: Okay. Thank you. However, they have not correctly specified the explanation of p value as p value of the F test that I mentioned above. Am I right that at every step it is performing a F test?